# How Can I Properly Use WooCommerce Subscriptions API in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, subscription, woocommerce-subscriptions

Documentation is very scarce. I'm trying to create some code that uses WooCommerce subscriptions (a plugin for WooCommerce) API to get a list of subscriptions and all of the details of each subscription. The docs and examples out there are just so scarce and weak I can't get it right. The following code didn't produce any errors but isn't outputting any subscriptions (just a blank page). How can I list all the details of all the subscriptions?

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['Action']))
{
    $Action = $_REQUEST['Action'];
    switch($Action)
    {
        case "ValidateSubscription":
            chdir("../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-subscriptions/classes");
            include '../../woocommerce/woocommerce.php';
            //include '../woo-includes/woo-functions.php';
            //include '../woo-includes/class-wc-dependencies.php';
            include 'class-wc-subscriptions-manager.php';

            $Subscriptions = WC_Subscriptions_Manager::get_all_users_subscriptions();
            print_r($Subscriptions);
            break;
        default:
            echo "invalid action";
    }
}else
{
    echo "no action specified";
}
```

Comment: Do you just want a list of all subscriptions that currently have users? Or a list of subscriptions regardless of whether or not a user is assigned?

Comment: I would like to list all of the subscriptions of a user complete with all details about the subscriptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not how you include WordPress functions in external code.  Try this.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['Action']))
{
    $Action = $_REQUEST['Action'];
    switch($Action)
    {
        case "ValidateSubscription":

            include('../wp-load.php'); //Guessing this path based on your code sample... should be wp root

            $Subscriptions = WC_Subscriptions_Manager::get_all_users_subscriptions();
            print_r($Subscriptions);
            break;
        default:
            echo "invalid action";
    }
}else
{
    echo "no action specified";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Piggybacking on @ChuckMac's answer, I think it can be refined further by respecting WordPress's [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) and knowing at which point the various parts of WordPress are up and running. Pretty much all of WP is loaded by the `init` hook so that's a safe place to run functions that are "listening" for a `$_REQUEST` variable. You may be able to get away with `plugins_loaded` depending on your ultimate use case.

```
add_action( 'init', 'so_26193801_event_listener' );

function so_26193801_event_listener(){

    if(isset($_REQUEST['Action'])){
        $Action = $_REQUEST['Action'];
        switch($Action){
            case "ValidateSubscription":

                $Subscriptions = WC_Subscriptions_Manager::get_all_users_subscriptions();
                print_r($Subscriptions);
                break;
            default:
                echo "invalid action";
        } 
    } else {
        echo "no action specified";
    }
}
```